# jQuery scroll down to new dynamic element, then slideDown to see the effect of new element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using jQuery 1.10. I have the following:

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#copyright").offset().top
  }, 500);
$("<%= j(render 'shop') %>").hide().appendTo($("#shops")).slideDown("fast");
```

What it does is scroll down to the end of the page, then the new element is appended. But while it's scrolling, the new element is already slideDown.

Questions:

1. I want the user to be scrolled down to the bottom of the page, then see the new element slideDown to create a UX feeling that new element is created.
2. Bonus: You notice I scroll to `#copyright` which is at the footer instead. Actually I want it to scroll to the exact position where the new element will be appended (usually there are many `shops`, it will be appended after the last shop.

Note: These two lines of code are working, just need to tweak a little.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try this:

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#copyright").offset().top
  }, 500, function(){
    $("<%= j(render 'shop') %>").hide().appendTo($("#shops")).slideDown("fast");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First you can use done to know when the animate is done
look at the animate example:

```
    $( "p" ).animate({
      height: 200,
     width: 400,
     opacity: 0.5
     }, 1000, "linear", function() {
      alert( "all done" );
   });
```

please look at the following example:
http://api.jquery.com/animate/

The function in the end is the done event

in addition you can detect when is user reach specific element in order to start your animation
you can use something like this:

```
jQuery(
      function($)
      {
        $('#flux').bind('scroll', function()
           {
            if($(this).scrollTop() + 
               $(this).innerHeight()
               >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight)
            {
              alert('end reached');
            }
          })
      }

);
```